# How do you remove rows after changing the item in a JPA OneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, one-to-one

How do you get a OneToOne item to automatically remove with JPA/Hibernate?  I would expect simply setting the OneToOne item to be null in the class that contains would be smart enough to allow Hibernate to delete it.

Given a simple object, simplified:

```
@Entity
public class Container {
    private Item item;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Item getItem() { return item; }

    public void setItem(Item newItem) { item = newItem; }
}
```

When an Item is set on Container an Container is persisted with merge a row gets inserted.

```
Container container = new Container();
container.setItem(new Item());
container = entityManager.merge(container);
// Row count is 1
```

But when the item is set null, or to another item, the old object still exists in the table.

```
container.setItem(null);
container = entityManager.merge(container);
// Row count is STILL 1, leaving orphaned rows.
```

So, how do I remove these OneToOne orphans?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I am using a partial solution: If Car contains Driver then I put an @CascadeType(cascade=CasadeType.ALL) on car.driver so the driver goes away when the car does, then I avoid replacing the Driver object when possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm *guessing* that the reasone behind hibernate not allowing `DELETE_ORPHAN` to `OneToOne` relations is related to [this issue](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3930?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=33303#action_33303).

If you **really** want this bad, you can hack your way with these steps:

- transform your *OneToOne* relation into a *OneToMany*:
- add a method just to get the first element of the child's collection (this is optional but handy)
- use the *DELETE_ORPHAN* annotation

Of course, this is a big hack.

Answer (score 1):

As JPA 2.0 has been released for a very long time now, you could simply use:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to

```
@OneToOne
@Cascade(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

See also my answer on similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549961/hibernate-removing-item-from-a-list-does-not-persist/550441#550441).

Comment: Works fine, thank you.  I am okay with using Hibernate-specific annotations until JPA 2.0.

Comment: Ignore that, updated test reveals the approach above does *not* work.  According to Hibernate team member Emmanuel delete-orphan is not supposed to work with OneToOne http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2287278

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in JPA without tying yourself to Hibernate's implementation.

So yes, as Foxy says, you can use `org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType` instead of the standard JPA annotation, which allows you to specify `DELETE_ORPHAN`. If you want to use the JPA abstraction, you must delete orphans yourself as of yet.